# Pass directories from pipeline as Powershell named parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, pipeline

I try to write a Powershell script that accepts directories from the pipeline as named parameter. My parameter declaration looks like

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)] [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]] $PsPath)
```

My problem is that the call

```
gci c:\ -Directory | MyScript
```

results in only the last element of the result of `gci` being in the input array. What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap up your execution code into a PROCESS block:

```
function MyScript {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$true)] 
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]] $PsPath
    )

    PROCESS {
        $PsPath
    }
}

gci c:\ -Directory | MyScript
```

Don Jones has a nice rundown of the BEGIN, PROCESS, & END blocks here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx